# Django models objects return None

Tags: python, django

I have this model in my Django app.

```
class Kilometer(models.Model):
    kilometers = models.IntegerField()
```

It work when with a form I save data on my database (I can see the objects on the admin page) but I have issue when I want to access the data in django shell.

```
>>> from forms.models import Kilometer
>>> test = Kilometer(1)
>>> print(test)
Kilometer object (1)
>>> print(test.kilometers)
None
```

I have the same problem with all my models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1` is the primary key, if you want to construct a `Kilometer` with as `kilometers = 1`, you construct  this with:

```
test = Kilometer(kilometers=1)
```

or you can work with a positional parameter where the primary key is set to `None`:

```
#     primary key ↓
test = Kilometer(None, 1)
#           kilometers ↑
```

Or if you want to determine the kilometers of an record with primary key `1` for example, you can fetch the `Kilometer` object with:

```
kms = Kilometer.objects.get(pk=1)
```

you can also reduce the bandwidth if you are only interested in the kilometers with:

```
kms = Kilometer.objects.only('pk', 'kilometers').get(
    pk=1
)
```

regardless how you fetch the `Kilometer` object, you can then fetch the number of kilometers with:

```
kms.kilometers
```

Comment: I want to get the kilometers from the Kilometer object which primary key = 1 (the object with primary key = 1 and kilometers = 10 already exist, so i want to get 10)

Comment: The you fetch this with `kms = Kilometer.objects.get(pk=1)`, then `kms` is a `Kilometer` object, so you access this then with `kms.kilometers`.